# How to move content of div into another

Tags: javascript, jquery

If i have for example divs with the class="text1", that have an a-tag with the class"text" over them.

```
 <a class="text">ClickHere1</a>
  <div class="text1" style="display: none">
   <p>Hey</p>
   <p>Ho</p>
  </div>
 <a class="text">ClickHere2</a>
  <div class="text1" style="display: none">
   <p>Hey</p>
   <p>Ho</p>
  </div>

 <div id="Content">
 </div>
```

How can i move the content of the class="text1" into the div with the id="Content" when the user clicks on an a-tag that is directly over the div wit class"text1". Or better said that when an user clicks on an a-tag only the content of the next div with the class="text1" is appended to the div with the id:Content.

Also im asking me how i can insure that in the div with the id:Content always only content of one div is displayed!

Thanks and i hope you  understand me !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want to move, or copy?

To copy the text:

```
$(".text").click(function() {
    $("#Content").html($(this).next(".text1").html());
});
```

If you want to move the text, use

```
$(".text").click(function() {
    $("#Content").html($(this).next(".text1").html());
    $(this).html('');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:

```
$("a.text").on("click",function(){
   $("#Content").html(  $(this).next(".text1").html() );
})
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4w3Hy/1/

Comment: It would be nice if only the content of one div with class text1 is displayed in the div Content! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested it, but you're looking for something like this. This should give you an idea

```
$(function(){
   $(".text").click(function(){
     var contentClone = $(this).next().html().clone();
      contentClone.insert($("#Content"))

   });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Moving the content

```
$("a.text").click(function(){
$("#Content").html($("this")next().html());
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
$('.text').on('click', function(){
    $('#Content').html($(this).next('div.text1').html());
});
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/E7env/)